# How to plot a stacked seaborn histogram colored from a different column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

My dataset is like this

```
 Days     Visitors

Tuesday    23
Monday     30
Sunday    120
Friday     2
Friday    30
Tuesday   13
Monday    20
Saturday  100
```

How can I plot a histogram for this dataset, but assume it as a large dataset(560030 rows), not just only these values.

Actually I want to have days on x-axis and Visitors on Y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `seaborn`, which is an API for matplotlib.

  - [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html)
  - [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot)
- This will show the distribution of the number of visitors for each day of the week.

#### `sns.histplot`

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # for test data
import random  # for test data
import calendar  # for test data

# test dataframe
np.random.seed(365)
random.seed(365)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Days': random.choices(calendar.day_name, k=1000), 'Visitors': np.random.randint(1, 121, size=(1000))})

# display(df.head(6))
        Days  Visitors
0     Friday        83
1     Sunday        53
2   Saturday        34
3  Wednesday        92
4    Tuesday        45
5  Wednesday         6

# plot the histogram
sns.histplot(data=df, x='Visitors', hue='Days', multiple="stack")
```

[image]

- Once the histogram is plotted, if the legend needs to be moved, use of the workaround found in [seaborn issue: Not clear how to reposition seaborn.histplot legend #2280](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2280), may be necessary.

#### `sns.displot`

- This option most clearly conveys the daily distribution of visitor counts

```py
sns.displot(data=df, col='Days', col_wrap=4, x='Visitors')
```

[image]

### Barplot

- [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)
- This will show the sum of all visits for a given day

```py
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Days', y='Visitors', estimator=sum, ci=None)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]